# FBSDKGraphRequest how to get profile cover photo?

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I am having difficulty fetching the cover profile picture...

Here I get the profie image:

```
let userProfile = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large"

                    let profilePictureUrl = NSURL(string: userProfile)

                    let profilePictureData = NSData(contentsOfURL: profilePictureUrl!)
                    if (profilePictureData != nil) {

                        let profileFileObject = PFFile(data:profilePictureData!)
                        currentUser.setObject(profileFileObject!, forKey: "profilePicture")
                    }
```

Which works great.

And now here I am trying to get the cover picture:

```
let coverPicture = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/cover?type=large"


                    let coverPictureUrl = NSURL(string: coverPicture)
                    let coverPictureData = NSData(contentsOfURL: coverPictureUrl!)
                    if (coverPictureData != nil) {

                        let coverFileObject = PFFile(data:profilePictureData!)
                        currentUser.setObject(coverFileObject!, forKey: "coverPicture")
                    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work?!

If anyone can help, please do :)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I was working with Graph Api, but as far as I know you cannot access the user's cover photo directly, even though there a field `cover` in the API.

The best approach I can think of is to request the user's photo albums with:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/albums"
```

In the response object you'll find an album with the name "Cover Photos":

```
  "created_time": "2016-01-01T20:00:00+0000",
  "name": "Cover Photos",
  "id": "123456789101112"
```

With  `{id)/picture` you can then get the cover photo.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Sorry, for me it's my first time! How would I actually implement that into my code?

Comment: Sorry, i cannot provide any code at the moment. Just look at the graph api explorer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to validate.

1. Select Get Token -> Get User Token
2. Submit a request with `me/albums` to get all your albums
3. Search for the album called "Cover Photos" and submit a new request with the id of the album like this `id/picture`. This will give you the link to your cover photo. Now just do the same in your code with the FacebookSDK.

Comment: I had a look and several tries..But no luck!

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful for getting facebook cover image.

```
 let emailRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name, id,cover"], tokenString: result?.token.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: "GET")
    _ = emailRequest?.start(completionHandler: { (nil, resultParameters, error) in
         if(error == nil) {
                 if let cover = (params?["cover"] as? NSDictionary)["source"]{ 
                    var coverUrl = cover as?  String
           }
        }
})
```